# How to tell if the current user is authenticated in Firebase using Django

Tags: python, django, firebase, firebase-authentication, pyrebase

I'm using Django with Pyrebase to access Firebase for authentication and logins. I'm new to all of them so bear with me.

I think I am able to successfully log the user in, but at that point I can't figure out how to change the html file to only show certain parts if the user is logged in.

I've tried `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` as well as `{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}` as well as `{% request.user.is_authenticated %}` and `{% request.current_user.is_authenticated %}` but all of them act as if they've returned false even though the user is authenticated via `user = authe.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)`.

Here's my views.py:

```
def login(request):
    # Rendering login page
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/login.html',
        {
            'title': 'Login',
            'message': 'Login to your account',
            'year': datetime.now().year
        }
    )

def postlogin(request):
    email=request.POST.get('username')
    password=request.POST.get('password')
    try:
        # if there is no error then log in the user with given email and password
        user = authe.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)

    except:
        message="Invalid credentials."
        print("invalid")
        return render(request,"app/login.html",{'message':message })
    session_id=user['idToken']
    request.session['uid']=str(session_id)
    return render(request,"app/home.html",{"email":email})
```

And my login.html:

```
{% if request.current_user.is_authenticated %} 
<form id="logoutForm" action="/logout/" method="post" class="navbar-right">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><span class="navbar-brand">Hello {{ user.username }}!</span></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>

{% else %}

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log in</a></li>
</ul>

{% endif %}
```

How do I show the top part in the login.html only if the user is logged in?

Comment: user = authe.sign... should be user = auth.sign... according the the pyrebase docs page.  Is that a typo in your question?

Comment: No, it's not. I followed some tutorial and it had firebase.auth() imported as authe. I guess I followed it even though it's weird. Earlier on in the code I do have ```firebase=pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
authe = firebase.auth()
database=firebase.database()``` so that can't be the problem.

Comment: I'm not an expert in pyrebase, but if the default django.auth is being bypassed, then is_authenticated might need to be replaced.  Eg, You could test for request.session.uid instead.